# iOS open application on start up

Tags: ios

I have a application for ipad security, i need to start this app on start up(i.e immediately after booting ). I don't know whether this is possible or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Short answer: its not possible.

Comment: ipad security ? what is that ? iOS is a censored platform and you can manage nothing ...

Comment: There is probably a jailbroken solution. If you are going to release on the App Store it is not possible / allowed.

Comment: According to this post - http://lithium3141.com/2012/02/18/ios-launch-on-boot-apps-fact-or-fiction/ you can. But, it is only for VoIP and will be taken down from the App Store if it is not.

Answer (score 2):

No this is not possible on the iOS.

As stated by [David Rönnqvist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/608157/david-ronnqvist) on a jailbroke device this is possible.

Comment: At least not if you are going to release on the App Store. There is probably a jailbroken solution.

Answer (score 0):

Only possible if you have control of the devices that will be running the app, and have them jailbroken.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to run an app on startup.

Depending on what you're trying to do you may be able to achieve your "Security" goal using Configuration Profiles.

Heres what they can do:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html

You can manage them using Apple Configurator
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator/id434433123?mt=12

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to do something under an Enterprise Account, if this is an in-house application; but you would have to ask Apple. For the App Store, no.

Answer (score 0):

To start an app, on booting of any device, you should have access to the Kernel, where you can customise it accordingly. You can get access to kernel level only on Linux OS because it is openSource.
In your case you will not get the access, because iOS is proprietary, unless you do some hack and if you succeed also apple will not accept your app.So better rethink what you are trying to achieve.

Good luck.